# Как вытащить необходимое значение из тега?

Tags: python, html, beautiful-soup

Как под записью в одноклассниках на странице какой-либо группы получить количество поделившихся этой записью?

Пыталась реализовывать так

```
user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random

header = {
    'user-agent': user,
}

url = 'https://ok.ru/moscow/topic/154516982323413'
response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
tags = soup.findAll('ul', class_='widget-list')
```

Думала дальше таких способом через find находить нужный тег, но даже в переменную tags не попадает нужное значение, хоть по html-коду все смотрела и он должен был быть

Comment: По какому html коду вы смотрели?

Comment: Каким образом он был получен?

Comment: я открыла пост и через инструменты разработчика смотрела, нашла место, где хранится значение нужное, но не получается его вытащить с помощью python

Comment: Потому здесь requests.get(url) вы делаете не такой же GET запрос как делает его ваш браузер.

Comment: я не понимаю, к чему вы ведете

Comment: Я к тому что распечатайте response.text и там нет тэга который нужен вам

Comment: Вам нужно добавить user-agent для начала потом и всё остальное

Comment: добавила, но ничего не изменилось

Comment: И не изменится, здесь за вас никто решать не будет задачу, вам на вашу ошибку я указал, думайте.

Comment: И кстати в коде тоже не чего не изменилось, вам на слово верить что вы добавили, кстати что вы добавили то?

Comment: Будьте активнее это вам нужно а не мне или ещё кому то.

Comment: И последнее приведите минимально воспроизводимый пример

Comment: пример добавила.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134759/discussion-between--and--).